# How to properly let the user enter a grade in the first output and show the second output base?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int grade;
    cout << ("Enter a grade input : ");
    cin >> grade;
    
    if (grade >= 94 && grade <= 100){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.00";
    }   
    if (grade >= 88.50 && grade <= 93.39){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.25";
    }
    if (grade >= 83 && grade <= 88.49){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.50";
    }
    if (grade >= 77.5 && grade <= 82.99){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.75";
    }
    if (grade >= 72 && grade <= 77.49){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.00";
    }    
    if (grade >= 65.5 && grade <= 71.99){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.25";
    }
    if (grade >= 61 && grade <= 65.49){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.50";
    }
    if (grade >= 55.5 && grade <= 60.99){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.75";
    }
    if (grade >= 50 && grade <= 55.49){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 3.00";
    }
    else if (grade > 100 && grade < 0) 
        cout << (" ! Wrong data ");
}
```

That's my code, it is a selection control structure using `if()` condition. My problem is I want to input the grades from 100 to 55.49 and the output is displaying the grades 100 to 55.49, and the second output shows the real grade like, the equivalent of the 94 grade is 1.00. If I type less than 0 and greater than 100 it shows the output "Wrong Data".

Comment: _`int grade;`_ you are aware,  which precision can be stored in an `int` data type, aren't you?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Also, you can't precisely compare an `int` with float literals.

Comment: An integer has no fractional part.

Comment: `if (grade > 100 && grade < 0)` can a number be both greater than 100 and less than 0 at the same time?

Comment: @digito_evo e

if I run the code, the output shows "Enter your grade" and then If I type 94 and press enter, the second output shows "Your Grade is 1.00" and if I type less that 0 or more than 100, the output shows "Wrong Data"

Comment: But still, what happens if you input 93.395? ... hint you need only one comparisson per if.

Comment: @drescherjm nope

Comment: So then you want to use || instead of && here: `if (grade > 100 && grade < 0)`

Comment: @digito_evo thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Please accept any answer that helped you most as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are reading the input using an `int`, which can't handle floating-point values. For example, if you typed in `55.49`, you would receive only `55`, leaving `.49` in the input buffer waiting to be read.  You need to use `float` or `double` instead of `int`.

After fixing that, there are still some other problems.

`if (grade > 100 && grade < 0)` will always be false, as a number can't be both "greater than 100" AND "less than 0".  You need to the `||` (logical OR) operator, not the `&&` (logical AND) operator.

Also, there is a gap in your logic where grades `93.4-93.99` and `< 50` are being ignored. In fact, your `if`s can be simplified quite a bit.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double grade;
    cout << "Enter a grade input : ";
    if (!(cin >> grade)){
        cout << " ! Bad data ";
    }
    else if (grade > 100 || grade < 0){
        cout << " ! Wrong data ";
    }
    else if (grade >= 94){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.00";
    }   
    else if (grade >= 88.5){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.25";
    }
    else if (grade >= 83){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.50";
    }
    else if (grade >= 77.5){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 1.75";
    }
    else if (grade >= 72){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.00";
    }    
    else if (grade >= 65.5){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.25";
    }
    else if (grade >= 61){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.50";
    }
    else if (grade >= 55.5){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 2.75";
    }
    else if (grade >= 50){
        cout << "Your output grade is: 3.00";
    }
    else{
        cout << ...; // <-- add something here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and short solution can be like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    double grade;
    std::cout << "Enter a grade input: ";
    std::cin >> grade;

    if ( grade > 100 || grade < 50 )
    {
        std::cout << "Wrong data!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your output grade is: ";
    }

    if ( grade >= 94 && grade <= 100 )
    {
        std::cout << "1.00";
    }
    else if ( grade >= 88.50 && grade <= 93.39 )
    {
        std::cout << "1.25";
    }
    else if ( grade >= 83 && grade <= 88.49 )
    {
        std::cout << "1.50";
    }
    else if ( grade >= 77.5 && grade <= 82.99 )
    {
        std::cout << "1.75";
    }
    else if ( grade >=72 && grade <= 77.49 )
    {
        std::cout << "2.00";
    }
    else if ( grade >= 65.5 && grade <= 71.99 )
    {
        std::cout << "2.25";
    }
    else if ( grade >= 61 && grade <= 65.49 )
    {
        std::cout << "2.50";
    }
    else if ( grade >= 55.5 && grade <= 60.99 )
    {
        std::cout << "2.75";
    }
    else if ( grade >= 50 && grade <= 55.49 )
    {
        std::cout << "3.00";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to your question, but having a lot of if's is fragile code (hard to maintain, it is easy to make a small typo and it will be hard to find etc.. etc..) Learn to look for repeating patterns in your code and try to replace them with functions. The for loops in this code are range based : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for. const means the program cannot change the value of the variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// put all the values at which your function output changes into an array of doubles    
std::array<double, 8> threshold_values{ 94.0, 88.5, 83.0, 77.5, 72.0, 65.5, 61.0, 55.5 }; 

// looking at your code, grade starts at 1.0 and increases by 0.25 at each
// threshold value
const double base_grade = 1.0;
const double grade_step = 0.25;

// so now we need to make a function that uses the real information
// from data above to calculate a grade.

// version of get_grade that will explain itself while it runs.
double get_grade_verbose(const double input)
{
    double grade = base_grade;
    for (const auto& threshold : threshold_values)
    {
        if (input > threshold)
        {
            std::cout << "input : " << input << " is greater then " << threshold << ", grade will be : " << grade << "\n";
            return grade;
        }
        
        std::cout << "input : " << input << " was smaller then " << threshold << " so increasing grage to ";
        grade += grade_step;
        std::cout << grade << "\n";
    }

    return grade;
}

// version without output    
double get_grade(const double input)
{
    double grade = base_grade;

    for (const auto& threshold : threshold_values)
    {
        if (input > threshold) return grade; // done
        grade += grade_step;
    }

    return grade;
}


int main()
{
    double input = 84.0;

    if ((input >= 0.0 ) && (input <= 100.0))
    {
        std::cout << "grade = " << get_grade(input) << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "invalid input\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `constexpr` in this case.

Comment: Didn't really matter in this example since there is no compile time evaluation. And I think there's already enough detail for OP to process for today ;).